# R: How to average 30 minute increment data points into a daily average, and eventually having a table with average daily values for a year in R

Tags: r

I have groundwater elevation data (WSE), in 30 minute increments for a 10 month time span. I am trying to average the groundwater elevation into daily values. Ideally, my final table would have a date and the average groundwater elevation for the day. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I attached a pic of my dataset.

[image: TheData]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Use package lubridate tu wxtract the dates from your first column, group by date, calculate the average WSE per day.

Comment: Simply extract the date value (midnight hour) and aggregate. [Research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) for implementation, give it an earnest try, them and come back with *specific* issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dplyr` and `lubridate` packages
you can create unique groups for each day, and calculate the mean of the values on that day (i.e. average of all 30 min time interval values on that day)

```
# Simulate your dataset
date_df <- data.frame(
  datetime = seq(
    from = as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00"),
    to   = as.POSIXct("2020-01-10 00:00"),
    by   = "30 min"
    )
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(val = rnorm(nrow(.)))  

# group by day, month, and year on 30 minute datetime intervals, then take mean of value within each group
date_df <- 
  date_df %>%  
  dplyr::mutate(
    day   = lubridate::day(datetime),
    month = lubridate::month(datetime),
    year  = lubridate::year(datetime)
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(day, month, year) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(
    avg_gw_elev = mean(val, na.rm = T)
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    datetime = as.Date(paste0(year, "-", month, "-", day))
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::select(datetime, avg_gw_elev)

head(date_df)

  # A tibble: 6 x 2
  datetime   avg_gw_elev
  <date>           <dbl>
1 2020-01-01      0.120 
2 2020-01-02      0.0295
3 2020-01-03     -0.0850
4 2020-01-04     -0.0367
5 2020-01-05      0.201 
6 2020-01-06      0.0132
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding to me! I am getting an error saying "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format". It is currently has a format of, "5/19/2021 12:000". Its slightly a bit different than the simulated data. Is it because I have "/" instead of"-" as seperators?

Comment: I figured it out! Because of you! I cheated a little bit and formatted the date into unambiguous format in Excel. hahah :)